# How do I control the height of the main content area no matter how much text is in there?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to control the main height of the content area. I don't want to set a fixed height. How would I do that to make it fluid up and down.

Currently, if there is a lot of text, the main text area overlaps on the footer. If there is only a little bit of text, the footer is way down on the page.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9j9rsz2/58/

Here's my HTML

```
    <body id="bodyId" align="center">
<div id="outerWrapDiv">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headerWrap">
    <div id="mktHeader">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://www.play-itproductions.net/images/standardlogos/dvd-logo.gif" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="innerWrapDiv">


<!-- START TEMPLATE HTML - EDIT THIS SECTION -->
<div id="mktContent">
<!-- Base of Landing Page Content -->
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>

<!-- END TEMPLATE HTML -->

</div>
</div>

<div id="footerWrap">
    <div id="mktFooter">
        <div class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2014 Microsoft, Inc.</div>  
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Here's my css:

```
#bodyId {
background: #232323;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height:18px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

div#outerWrapDiv {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

div#innerWrapDiv {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    }

</style>

<!-- START TEMPLATE CSS - EDIT THIS SECTION -->

<style>
/* Note: You can also change these in the specific Landing Pages*/

/* Width of Full Page */

    div#innerWrapDiv {
     width: 960px;
    }

img {
    border:none;    
}
#wrapper {
    background:#e2e3e4;
}

/* Main Header Area  */
div#headerWrap {
    background: transparent;
    width:100%;
}

div#mktHeader {
    border-top:10px solid #f66511;
    background:#fff;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:960px;  
    }

#logo {
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto; 
    }

/* Main Content Area - Controls height of page */
div#mktContent {
    background:#fff;
    height: 1500px;
    position: relative;
    }

/* Footer Area */
div#footerWrap {
    background: #232323;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    width:100%; 
}
div#mktFooter {
    background:#232323;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:11px; 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width:960px;
    }

/* Footer links and Copyright */

    .copyright{
        color:#fff;
        font-size:11px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove height and set `overflow: auto` :

```
div#mktContent {
    background:#fff;
    overflow:auto;/*Replace height with overflow*/
    position: relative;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9j9rsz2/59/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto;` and remove `height`:

```css
div#mktContent {
    background:#fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Should I take the height out of the div#mktContent tag?

Comment: Do you wanna set it like dynamic or what? Yes, you need to take the height!

Comment: Can I send you a link to check out? I'm still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Adding overflow:auto and removing the height suggested initially by @Alek will work, but why not start using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to do all your layout heavy lifting, and save yourself a lot of fiddly details, speeding up your front-end development.  If you're interested you can also see how Bootstrap does all it's magic by looking at the source as CSS, LESS, or SASS.  If you haven't used it before, start reading the overview then then look at the Grid.